# Animating TransformationController

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

So I have a picture in an interactive viewer. I want to reset the Pan and Zoom every time the user is done changing it. I am successfully able to do this using the `TransformationController` and `onInteractionEnd` callback. However, of course, the reset is very abrupt, so I would like to animate it to provide a smooth transition. I have no experience with Flutter animations and this is the best I could come up with.

```
class _PhotoZoom extends State<PhotoZoom> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  
  TransformationController transformationController =
      new TransformationController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: InteractiveViewer(
              transformationController: transformationController,
              child: Image.network(imageUrl),
              onInteractionEnd: (ScaleEndDetails details) {
                _resetPanZoom();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  _resetPanZoom() {
    AnimationController animationController =
        AnimationController(duration: const Duration(seconds: 2), vsync: this);

    Animation<Matrix4> animation = Matrix4Tween(
            begin: transformationController.value, end: Matrix4.identity())
        .animate(animationController);

    transformationController.value = animation.value;
  }
}
```

What I am trying to do is smoothly change the controller's changed `Matrix4` variable to `Matrix4.identity()` which will reset the image to original Pan and Zoom. But yes this doesn't work as I am probably doing something wrong. What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: add a listener to your `animation`, inside that listener call `transformationController.value = animation.value` and finally call `animationController.forward(from: 0.0)`

Comment: actually `animationController.forward()` is enough as its value is `0.0` after creating

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: and of course `transformationController.value = animation.value` should be called only in the listener, but I believe you already did it